# Python Error - Google Foobar

Tags: python-2.7, google-chrome, runtime-error

To anyone who has done Google's Foobar challenge before, have you ever encountered an error like this?

```
Verifying solution...
{
"bytes" : "CAAaIgogQ291bGQgbm90IGZpbmQgJ2Fuc3dlcicgZnVuY3Rpb24"
}
```

I've tested my solution in Visual Studio, and it works fine, and it gives accurate output. I only have 36 hours remaining to submit my solution, and this is the final challenge, so I would really like to get credit for completing it. Here's the code I'm trying to verify:

```
from fractions import *
from math import factorial as fac

def cycle_index(n):
    return [(coeff(term), term) for term in foo(n, n)]

def foo(n, lim):
    soln_set = []
    if n > 0:
        for x in range(lim, 0, -1):
            if x == 1:
                soln_set.append([(1, n)])
            else:
                for y in range(int(n / x), 0, -1):
                    recurse = foo(n - x * y, x - 1)
                    if len(recurse) == 0:
                        soln_set.append([(x, y)])
                    for soln in recurse:
                        soln_set.append([(x, y)] + soln)
    return soln_set

def coeff(term):
    val = 1
    for x, y in term:
        val *= fac(y) * x ** y
    return Fraction(1, val)

def cross(cycle_a, cycle_b):
    term = []
    for len_a, freq_a in cycle_a:
        for len_b, freq_b in cycle_b:
            lcm = len_a * len_b / gcd(len_a, len_b)
            term.append((lcm, int(len_a * freq_a * len_b * freq_b / lcm)))
    return term

def answer(w, h, s):
    total = 0
    cycidx_cols = cycle_index(w)
    cycidx_rows = cycle_index(h)
    for col_coeff, col_cycle in cycidx_cols:
        for row_coeff, row_cycle in cycidx_rows:
            coeff = col_coeff * row_coeff
            cycle = cross(col_cycle, row_cycle)
            value = 1
            for _, power in cycle:
                value *= s ** power
            total += coeff * value
    return total
```

I found someone else's solution last week and verified it through Foobar, but I wanted to write my own to get a deeper understanding. I've compared results side-by-side, and they are exact, so I know my code gives accurate results.

Out of curiosity, I just retried verifying the other person's solution again, and now I am getting the same error with a slightly different output even though it worked just fine when I tried last week:

```
Verifying solution...
{
"bytes" : "CAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQAQ"
}
```

I'm not sure where else to go. I was so excited that I had come up with my own solution to the challenge, but now I'm panicking that it won't matter. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE - June 29, 2018, 6:00pm CST**
The deadline passed for me last night, and I was unable to submit my code in time. I made sure to use the `recruitme` command before time ran out just in case I got booted out. However, I am still able to view my current status, and it let me request another Level 5 challenge. So, I will be checking periodically to see if the test cases start showing up again, and I will be sure to update this when they do. I would highly recommend that anyone on lower levels wait until I confirm that this issue is fixed before attempting to request another challenge.

**UPDATE - June 30, 2018, 5:00am CST**
According to the pattern found by @RobertAnsel, I have completed the challenge. I confirmed this pattern by hardcoding the `answer` function to output solutions to the test cases given in the instructions. The resulting errors matched exactly with the predicted output. I also found an interesting thread on Google's Support Forum ([linked here](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0glB446CoqrQ/?hl=en)) where something similar happened to a bunch of Foobar challengers. It seems like their error was fixed by Google after about three days, but unfortunately, it also looks like a lot of people who timed out were not given another chance. Nevertheless, this will probably resolve itself within the next day or two. I will continue trying to verify and submit my solution until I am successful.

**UPDATE - July 4, 2018, 12:00am CST**
This issue seems to have been more or less resolved. Refer to the chosen answer for more details. Thanks a ton to @RobertAnsel for all the help! Some additional info: I was able to verify my current challenge, but upon submission, I was told that my time for the problem had expired. After logging in again, I was able to request a new challenge. I noticed I was also able to use the `recruitme` command again. I am not sure if this means they did not receive the first request or if you are allowed to use that command multiple times. Regardless, I am relieved that I am able to continue forward with Foobar. Best of luck to the rest of you!

Comment: I am having this exact same issue with the exact same `{
"bytes": "CAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQARABEAAQAA"
}` returned. Here's hoping this can be resolved.

Comment: It's seeming very likely this is something on their end then. Yeah, hopefully we can try again later today or tomorrow and everything will be fine.

Comment: Well, I've only got three hours left to complete this so I hope this doesn't boot me off the challenge.

Comment: That's frustrating. Oddly enough, I timed out on one question on level 3 and was given another chance to continue, so maybe you will too if this isn't resolved.

Comment: Tried clearing my cache, history, etc and nothing worked. Are you still having this problem?

Comment: Yes, the same thing is still happening.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem in the first challenge of level 3: `{ "bytes": "CAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQARAAEAEQAQ" }` Last night I got a different, much longer bytes string that decoded to something meaningful as per the advice @RobertAnsel gave, but after spending a couple hours this afternoon tweaking my solution (resolving that original issue and some others), I have no idea what else I can try. I submitted a couple bug reports via `feedback`, so hopefully this gets resolved.

Comment: I am having a similar issue as well on Level 3.  But my error string is "CAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQAQ" which although very similar is not the same as the other strings listed so far.  
Just for reference, I only had this issue with the "fuel injection perfection" problem, the other 2 level 3 problems passed with no issue.  Also, as Hyperfine noted, I first began experiencing this issue within the last 24 hours.  Just providing information in case we can try to isolate if it really is an issue on their end

Comment: @HenryHsu Your error string is the same as the last one listed in the original question above.

Comment: @HenryHsu Interestingly, now after fixing another bug, my message matches the one you're getting, and the one at the end of the original question. I wonder if that means it's correct?

Comment: @SamEstep  I wonder that too.  From the custom tests that I ran, my answers have been checking out.  I thought it was an efficiency issue since Level 3 answers have to not just be accurate, but fast as well.  That's the only thing left that I can think of?

Comment: I've finished level 4 (and level 5 if I would have been able to submit in time), and I can assure you that the only error message I got regarding runtime was something along the lines of "maximum runtime exceeded". It was very clear and definitely not encoded in Base64, so I am almost certain this is something on their end.

Comment: @NoOrangeJuice, based on my understanding of the output you posted (CAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQARABEAAQAA) You are still failing test cases 9 and 10.

Comment: @KodyPuebla Thanks for that piece of info Kody, that's very helpful.  Does seem weird as Hyperfine pointed out that most (all?) of the posts dealing with this specific issue seems to have popped up within the last day or two.

Comment: @RobertAnsel Hi Robert, how were you able to decode the issue with that string?  Just curious as I'd love to know what my error string (CAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQAQ) means

Comment: @RobertAnsel This actually makes a lot of sense. The bug is probably that their output is somehow getting encoded in base64 and being interpreted as an error regardless of the results of the test cases. All we can hope for now is that they allow everyone affected by this to have another chance.

Comment: @HenryHsu, from what I can tell, it seems to be base64, with 1 leading 2-byte chunk, and each remaining 2-byte chunk representing a specific test-case. When the final bit of that chunk is a 1 => passing, a 0 => failing. Yours (and everyone else with the same string), if I'm right, indicates all passing tests. Mostly I gathered this just by futzing with different people's errors here (base64 -> binary, 2 byte chunks): https://cryptii.com/base64-to-binary   Best of luck to you all!

Comment: @RobertAnsel Thanks for the explanation and the link Robert!  You're awesome  :)

Comment: question for you @KodyPuebla, you mentioned that you got another chance at level 3 when you timed out previously.  When you got your new challenge, were you able to complete that one without running into this error issue?  Would suck if we do get another chance and end up running into this bug again and then being right back to where we are now

Comment: @HenryHsu I finished level 3 about a month and a half ago, and this bug was not present then, so I was able to submit those without any problems. I would definitely recommend waiting for a little bit to request another challenge because we haven't seen any indication of this issue being fixed yet.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue. When logging in today, I edited my code and attempted to verify. The output stated that time had expired, even though I still had a day left. I logged out and logged back in and saw the challenge was no longer available but I'm still able to request a new challenge. I'd recommend giving them a few days to be on the safe side to ensure they've resolved the issue on their end.

Comment: lol classic programming con, dupe people into a fake interview where all you do is solve problems they can't for free while also being a guinea pig for whatever helper tools they are testing out

Comment: Thank you @Kody Puebla !  Unfortunately, I ran out of time and was not able to request a new challenge.  I was however able to get a new invite by repeating some of my searches that got me the invite in the first place.  With the new invite I was able to pickup where I left off in level 3 with a new challenge and finish it.  Submitted no problem.  Thank you for the updates and good luck with the rest of your challenges!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but that first "bytes" string is a base64 encoding of the following error message:

"Could not find 'answer' function".

I've done the Foobar challenge myself, and that should only happen if you are trying to verify a file that is missing a defined "answer" function, which obviously you are not. Are you certain that the spec they provide has 3 arguments vs an array with 3 items?

The second message (CAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQAQ), while valid base64, doesn't map to ASCII or UTF-8. After some closer analysis of some of the other strings others have posted, I've concluded that this is the base64 encoded version of the test output. It isn't very human readable, but I believe it is 11 2-byte chunks, the first of which is unhelpful, but the following 10 are the test result for each of the corresponding test cases. In the case of this message it converts to binary as:

```
0000100000000001 <- unknown pre-pended info
0001000000000001 <- passing test 1
0001000000000001 <- passing test 2
0001000000000001 <- passing test 3
0001000000000001 <- passing test 4
0001000000000001 <- passing test 5
0001000000000001 <- passing test 6
0001000000000001 <- passing test 7
0001000000000001 <- passing test 8
0001000000000001 <- passing test 9
0001000000000001 <- passing test 10
```

The '1's at the end of each of these lines indicates that all 10 tests are passing.

A failing test case is represented by the following string:

```
0001000000000000 <- failing test case
```

This should help you (and others) continue testing to achieve fully passing tests (you can complete your own analysis with tools like this one: https://cryptii.com/base64-to-binary),  but unfortunately this will not help you move forward with your final submission until Google remediates the issue on their end.

**UPDATE: July 2, 8PM PDT**
After reaching out to a couple of Google recruiters about the issue they were able to confirm that the issue was identified and is believed to be resolved today.
If you re-save your code after making a change to it (whitespace should be fine), you should be able to test and submit correctly. Alternatively, you may now be able to request a new challenge anyway.

Comment: The instructions read "Write a function answer(w, h, s) that takes 3 integers and returns...", so I am certain there are three arguments. I could understand how I got that message the first time since I temporarily renamed that function. I might have forgotten to switch it back. But that is definitely not the case now, and I am only seeing the second error message now. It's too bad that one doesn't translate to anything useful.

Comment: Thanks for the base64 tip! I was able to use it to extract all the hidden test cases to the first level 3 challenge. However, when I try to `verify` or `submit` my solution (of whose correctness I am now fairly certain), I get the same mysterious error, with apparently no effect.

Comment: @SamEstep, I'm hoping to confirm a theory I have on the encoding scheme they are using. Was the error you mentioned having "after all" that you were failing test case #8? (per your CAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQARAAEAEQAQ output)

Comment: @RobertAnsel It was indeed, assuming that the first test case is numbered #1.

Comment: @KodyPuebla I'm still unable to submit, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I was able to submit my solution yesterday

Answer (score 4):

There will be nothing for you to solve this issue, it is a issue on Google's site, as the Google Foobar API is responding with this message as I've found out.

Notherless your best bet will be to use the `feedback` command and give Google Foobar a feedback and mark it as a bug. This will be more likely to reach their attention and helping them to fix this issue!

Comment: How were you able to find out that these error messages are related to a fault with the Foobar API?  I mean, I hope it is and not something I forgot to address in my algorithm.  Were you able to decode the "CAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQAQ" string into an error message?

Comment: I were not able to decode the message `CAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQAQ`. But I've looked at what the API responds and searched a bit through the source code. The response of the API always gives you a score which is always `0` in my case and this does not change whatever you send a working or a wrong solution. I have an friend who is in Google Foobar aswell and it should respond with test cases if all tests were passed and such but not this encoded message we get.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Shawn!  Now I just wish they would fix it, lol.